# How to translate the middle item in a string with python?

Tags: python, internationalization

I want to add a i18n feature to my project.

Now I want to translate this sentence in the views.py file:

```
u"Please select {0} item".format(quantity)
```

I tried to do this in the product.po file:

```
msgid "Please select {0} item"
msgstr "请选择{0}项"
```

And change that sentence to this:

```
_ = request.translate
_(u"Please select {0} item".format(quantity))
```

But when I run it, it doesn't work.

How to deal with {0} in this case?

Comment: Did you save your .po file in UTF-8 (No BOM) format?

Comment: @Selcuk Thank you for your post. Yes, I am sure that the .po file in UTF-8 format. I changed the question. That way doesn't work, too.

Comment: @Selcuk It works! Thank you very much! If you write it down as a answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only wrap the string to be translated, excluding the format function. Try:

```
_(u"Please select {0} item").format(quantity)
```